# an error in WTForms, failing to call the form class

Tags: python, flask

This code raises an error when trying to call the form class.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField,SubmitField

app=Flask(__name__)

class infoform(Form):
    breed = StringField('what breed are you')
    submit=SubmitField('submit')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    breed =False
    form =infoform(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        breed= form.breed.data
        form.breed.data=''
    return  render_template('index.html',form=form,breed=breed)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expected an output of a form having a text field with a label of "what breed are you". But I get an error pointing to `form = infoform()` which I failed to understand.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: KeyError: 'A secret key is required to use CSRF.'

Comment: that is the error that I get, and even after setting a secrete key as app.config['SECRETE_KEY']='KFSFOIFFHIHFSFSLSVGSUIFU' it still raises the same error

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what error you have exactly, but generally speaking here is how you should use forms with `flask-wtf`, assuming that you are using the latest version ([0.14](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#creating-forms)), like me :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,SubmitField

app=Flask(__name__)

class Infoform(FlaskForm):
    breed = StringField('what breed are you')
    submit=SubmitField('submit')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    breed = False
    form = Infoform()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        breed= form.breed.data
        form.breed.data=''
    return  render_template('index.html',form=form,breed=breed)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Note that in the second line I import `FlaskForm` **and not** `Form`. And at the `InfoForm` class level, I inherit the `FlaskForm` class.

Finally, in agreement with the Python Enhancement Proposal 8 ([PEP8](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/)), which says that the name of a class must begin with a capital letter, I modified your `InfoForm` class ... Because readability counts